# How can I parse a page with Nokogiri when content is loaded using Javascript?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse some content from a [Twitch.tv website](http://es.twitch.tv/directory/game/League%20of%20Legends) as a learning exercise for Nokogiri.

When fetching the HTML document, I don't get the source that I see on Google Chrome, it seems the content is being loaded via Javascript and not on the initial GET request.

How can I use Nokogiri to parse a list of streams from that website? Or more generically, how can I parse content that is loaded dynamically after the DOM is finished loading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is json so you don't use nokogiri. For example:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
hash = JSON.parse open('http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top?limit=10&on_site=1').read
```

Comment: What is 'kraken' there? And when I remove the limit parameter I get an SSL error despite not changing HTTP request type. Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: I don't know what that is, I just noticed that the page loads json data from that url.